# message format for router (RTR) logs?

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud

I am trying to diagnose an issue.  Does anybody have an idea of what the format is for RTR log messages in Bluemix?

For example:

`somehost.mybluemix.net - [02/03/2017:16:00:23.428 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 306 "-" "-" 44.44.44.44:4444 x_forwarded_for:"55.5.55.55" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:abc-123 response_time:0.005884674 app_id:abc-123 x_global_transaction_id:"55555555"`

Comment: Also, does anybody understand what the value of "instance_id" means when it comes to RTR logs?  I see values of 0, 1, 2, and 3, but I only have a single instance of my application running so I would only expect to ever see a value of 0.  

Maybe the instance_id for RTR logs is the instance of the router itself and not the application that is actually being routed too???

Comment: Please describe the issue you are having. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for getting the best results when you ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am trying to analyze logs of my app(s) to see if there is some combination of requests that get the server-side into a bad state and cause it to throw an exception. I'm not asking for anybody to diagnose my particular issue. I would just like some more detailed information about RTR logs: what is the "message" format and what does "instance_id"  refer to.

Answer (score 3):

From v217 the format is:

```
<hostname> - [<time>] "<verb> <path> <http_spec>" <status> <request_bytes_received> <body_bytes_sent> <referer> <http_user_agent> x_forwarded_for:<x_forwarded_for> x_forwarded_proto:<x_forwarded_proto> vcap_request_id:<vcap_request_id> response_time:<response_time> app_id:<app_id>
```

Check here for older versions: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/logsearch-for-cloudfoundry/blob/ce1f81256094eba25368985fa08938631ef1a969/src/logsearch-config/src/logstash-filters/snippets/doppler.conf